# Finding node in tree

Tags: scala

I have a tree that can have multiple root nodes. The node is defined as:

```
case class Node[A] ( id: Int, data: A, var children: Option[Seq[Node[A]]], 
                        var parent: Option[Node[A]] )
```

Where id identifies the node, data is information related to the node, children a sequence of nodes, and parent points to the parent node.

The tree class is as follows:

```
case class Tree[A] ( var nodes: Option[Seq[Node[A]]] ) {

      def searchParent (searchId: Int): Option[Node[A]] = {
          nodes match {
              case Some(nodes) => {
                  for ( node <- nodes ) {
                    val parent = searchParent2(node,searchId)
                    parent match {
                      case Some(p) => {
                        parent
                      }
                      case None => None
                    }
                  }
                  None
              }
              case None => None
            }
      }

      def searchParent2 (node: Node[A], searchId: Int): Option[Node[A]] = {
            node.children match {
              case Some(nodes2) => {
                  for ( node2 <- nodes2 ) {
                    if (node2.id == searchId)
                      Some(node2)
                    else
                      searchParent2(node2,searchId)
                  }
                  None
              }
              case None => None
            }

    }

}
```

Problem is that when I search for a node based on its id, I always get None. What's wrong with this code?

Comment: Replace `Option[Seq[Node]]` with `Seq[Node]` and your code will be much cleaner

Comment: One problem I see is that you are not returning from the `for`, after the curly brackets you return `None` in both methods, plus, you don't need an option, just use an empty sequence for a node with no children.

Comment: @EndeNeu I added the None after the `for` assuming that it will not get there as I return from the `for`. When you say I'm not returning from the `for`, why is that?

Comment: There's no return statement (and you don't need one anyway), the last line will be the returned value of your method, in your case it's none. I strongly suggest that you have a look into scala basics (although in this case googling for for comprehensions should be enough) before trying to handle more complicated logic.